# How to dynamically add current date to a new instance of an object and push it to an array

Tags: javascript

I have set up a function to get the current date and time in the format I want:

```
function date(){
        var d = new Date();
        var minutes = d.getMinutes();
        var month = d.getMonth() +1;
        if(minutes<10){
            return (d.getDate() + "/" + month + "/" + d.getFullYear() + " " + d.getHours() + ":" + "0" + minutes);
        }else{
            return (d.getDate() + "/" + month + "/" + d.getFullYear() + " " + d.getHours() + ":" + minutes);}
        }
```

I created an `Object` that takes the values `(amount,date,type)`.  How can I set it up so with every new instance of the object the date value be generated by the function `date()` automatically so that when it gets pushed to the array `movements` a timestamp is added?

Here is my code:

```
var movements =[];

//transactions
var initialBalance = new Transaction(1000,"date","cash");
var addIn = new Transaction(500,"date","cash");
var addOut = new Transaction(-300,"date","card");

//add the transactions to the movements array
movements.unshift(initialBalance);
movements.push(addIn);
movements.push(addOut);
```

I would like to do this with pure JS.

Comment: What is `Transaction`?

Comment: Do you simply need your `Object`'s constructor to call the `date()` function and store it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe add the `date` function to the object

```
var Transaction = function(amount, type) {

    this.date = (function() {
        var d = new Date();
        var minutes = d.getMinutes();
        var month = d.getMonth() +1;
        if (minutes<10) {
            return (d.getDate() + "/" + month + "/" + d.getFullYear() + " " + d.getHours() + ":" + "0" + minutes);
        } else {
            return (d.getDate() + "/" + month + "/" + d.getFullYear() + " " + d.getHours() + ":" + minutes);
        }
    })();

    // now deal with amount and type...
}
```

The function will evaluate itself once you create the object.

Comment: Seems like a more sensible solution that the one I've offered.

Answer (score 1):

You could override push on your array...

```
var movements = [];
movements.push = function(transaction) {
    transaction.date = date();
    return Array.push(transaction);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it currently set up, you would simply replace `"date"` with the function call to `date()`:

```
//transactions
var initialBalance = new Transaction(1000,date(),"cash");
var addIn = new Transaction(500,date(),"cash");
var addOut = new Transaction(-300,date(),"card");
```

But, as others have suggested, there might be better ways to do what you are trying to do.